# PS Elements vs Lightroom for image management

Tags: lightroom, photo-management, photoshop-elements

**If I acquire Lightroom to use with my PS Elements program, should I move my database to Lightroom?**

I have used PS Elements for many years (currently PSE 12) and have a 40,000 image database. I Have long thought about adding Lightroom as a second program but have been concerned as to whether I would need to,  or should, convert my database to Lightroom.  I only shoot raw, and I know that the Lightroom raw editor is far superior to the one in Elements, so it would be logical to open all my files in Lightroom if I take the plunge.  I am extremely happy with the very capable database in Elements, making the possible conversion to Lightroom's database, a probable daunting task, something that I am very reluctant to do.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you want to keep from the Elements DB and move to LR that won't be in metadata? They are very different tools in that Elements is a destructive editor and LR is non-destructive. The LR DB tools are very powerful and I would be surprised to find out that much if any benefit exists to keeping the DB in Elements beyond the facial recognition feature. I also don't see what would be daunting about starting LR up and creating a new DB to point at the 40k images. Please explain further, and if you haven't download a trial and test out some of these theories and report back.

Comment: Also, not sure I'd agree that Lr's RAW editor is far superior--it's basically just using ACR.

Comment: Not sure if the RAW processing in LR is far superior.  It has a lot more features (HSL, tone curves etc) but it is based on the same engine and I would think for most purposes would perform similar quality RAW processing.  I would expect LR to be a lot more efficient if you're processing a lot of files.  If you love the PSE way of managing your catalog, you might just want to trial LR, add collections of new files for awhile and see if it grows on you.

Comment: But to answer your question, if you do use LR you would start in LR, do RAW processing, then edit in PSE if you require destructive editing.  So it would only make sense to me to manage your catalog in LR.

Comment: Lightroom can import your PSE database, which I can tell you definitely works just fine. Upgrading the DB shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Thanks to each of you who responded to my query.  I now feel more confident in migrating to Lightroom for image management and that it will simplify my workflow by opening raw images there. I'll start with a trial and if happy with the database, may just go directly to the Cloud combo of PS and Lightroom.